# trying to use switch with if else statement to make operations. but but syntax error appears?

Tags: javascript

i am a javascript beginner , tried to make a program to insert two inputs of numbers and insert an operator to make a mathematical function and make an alert if the input is not correct. i don't know why a syntax error appears after case + and doesn't work .is there other way to make the program?
any suggetions?
thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Wrap it with "" to make it a string type

Comment: Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots. http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few different issues with your code and I'll go over them one by one:

- First, note that `typeof` for `first_number` and `second_number` will be `number` regardless of the input. You want to check for `NaN` instead using the `isNaN` function.
- Second, you will want to wrap the cases of the switch statement in curly braces.
- Third, the case values themselves should be in quotes in this case.
- Fourth, you will want the `break` keyword after each of your cases to prevent them from falling through to the next case. There are valid use cases for that (such as multiple cases with the same block) but it's not what you want in this basic example.

All in all, your code should look like this, basically:

```js
var first_number = parseInt(prompt("Please enter a number"));
var second_number = parseInt(prompt("Please enter a number"));

if (isNaN(first_number) || isNaN(second_number))
{
    alert("Please enter valid numbers.");
}

var operator = prompt("Please enter an operator");

var result;

switch(operator)
{
    case "+":
        result = first_number + second_number;
        break;

    case "-":
        result = first_number - second_number;
        break;

    case "*":
        result = first_number * second_number;
        break;

    case "/":
        result = first_number / second_number;
        break;

    default:
        result = "Invalid operator.";
        break;
}

alert(result);
```

Lastly, please post your actual code in the contents of the post in future instead of an image.

Comment: You did a good job of addressing the issues in the code but missed one that you fixed in your code. Wrapping the case values in double quotes.

Comment: Oh yes, my bad. I forgot to explain that bit.